# Why if i use ngModel i can´t see the placeholder in a select/option?

Tags: angular, select, placeholder, ngmodel

i am using a select with ngModel to catch the value of the options, but when i render i dont have a placeholder as in the image

[image: I can´t see the placeholder]

This is the code:

```
<select  [value]="selected_tipo"   [(ngModel)]="selected_tipo"  >
      <option show="true" *ngFor="let tipo of tipos;"  value="{{tipo.tipos}}"  >{{tipo.descrip}}</option>
    </select>
```

And the TS code:

```
tipos = [
    {
      tipos: 'HEXO',
      descrip: 'Hora extra',
    },
    {
      tipos: 'HEXN',
      descrip: 'Hora extra Nocturna',
    }]

public selected_tipo: String = 'Select an option'
```

If i remove the ngModel i can see the placeholder but i can´t catch the value

[image: Placeholder works but i dont have ngModule and i cant catch the value]

The question is:

How can catch the value of the option and render the placeholder like the second image??

I tried with id in the select and document.getElemntById().value to catch the value without ngModel in TS, but it throws me an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another `option` for that.

```html
<select [value]="selected_tipo" [(ngModel)]="selected_tipo">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option show="true" *ngFor="let tipo of tipos" value="{{ tipo.tipos }}">
    {{ tipo.descrip }}
  </option>
</select>
```

You can even go as far as to remove the default value from the `ts` file altogether (or just set it to an empty string, to match the `value` of the `option` that we just added).

```js
public selected_tipo: String = '';
```